# Meteor collection insert allow throwing error

Tags: javascript, meteor

Currently I am just trying to check if the user is logged in before inserting an item.  I will eventually change this so only certain users can insert certain items, but for now I am just trying to make sure the user is logged in before adding an item to the DB.

This is my meteor method for inserting an item

```
Meteor.methods({
    addItem : function(newItem) {
        var item = {
                time: new Date(),
                type: newItem.type
        }
        console.log("User ID: "+Meteor.userId());
        console.log("item: " +item);
        Item.insert(Meteor.userId(), item);
    }
});
```

My allow statement

```
Item.allow({
    insert: function(userId, item){
        return userId != null;
    }
})
```

The error message in console

```
I20150630-23:27:29.811(-4)? User ID: null
I20150630-23:27:29.912(-4)? item: [object Object]
I20150630-23:27:29.917(-4)? Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: object is not a
 function
I20150630-23:27:29.918(-4)?     at writeCallback (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js
:313:1)
I20150630-23:27:29.918(-4)?     at Meteor.bindEnvironment.runWithEnvironment (pa
ckages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
```

EDIT:

after logging in the console prints

```
I20150630-23:31:43.006(-4)? User ID: So9WoeueDJ6oEWkKf
I20150630-23:31:43.016(-4)? item: [object Object]
I20150630-23:31:43.018(-4)?     at Meteor.bindEnvironment.runWithEnvironment (pa
ckages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
I20150630-23:31:43.017(-4)?     at writeCallback (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js
:313:1)
I20150630-23:31:43.017(-4)? Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: object is not a
 function
```

EDIT 2:

```
Item.allow({
    insert: function(userId, item){
        console.log("userId: "+userId);
        return userId != null;
    }
})

Meteor.methods({
    addItem : function(newItem) {
        var item = {
                time: new Date(),
                type: newItem.type
        }
        console.log("userID going into insert: "+Meteor.userId());
        Item.insert(item);
    }
});
```

output

```
I20150701-00:11:56.267(-4)? userID going into insert: null
```

and more importantly, the item gets added to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue it turns out was 2 fold.

One, the user_id doesn't get passed into the insert method

Two, the allow/deny ONLY works on client side inserts.

Since it is generally bad practice to do the insert client side (it's harder to secure and gives a lot of information to the would be attackers), it is best to just do the logic in your Meteor.methods functionality.

Final solution was to do the following:

```
Meteor.methods({
    addItem : function(newItem) {
        var item = {
                time: new Date(),
                type: newItem.type
        }
        if (Meteor.userId()){
            Item.insert(item);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert

`CollectionName.insert` takes an object you want to insert as the first argument and then a callback function to run as the second argument.

In your code you're putting in a string as the first argument and then an object as the second argument. That's why you have the message `object is not a function`:

```
Item.insert(Meteor.userId(), item);
```

Do something like:

```
if( Meteor.userId() ){
  // insert something
  Item.insert(item, function(error, idOfInsertedDocument){
    // do something if there is an error during insertion
    // or do something with the ID of the inserted document
  });
} else {
  // do something to notify the user that nothing can be inserted because there is no user
};
```

Comment: To expand on this, http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-allow : the userId is a default first argument of allow. So you dont have to pass the userId.

Comment: Correct. The `allow/deny` rules for collection operations function only on the server side. I don't know where the `Meteor Methods` are defined in the OP, but it's likely they're in `/lib` so the method will run on both the server and client. On the client, it's useful to check for `Meteor.userId()`

Comment: Both sections of code are in server/collection-methods.js.  Please see edit 2 as now it appears my Item.allow is being ignored

Comment: @PaulNispel please look at edit 2 in the origional question as it appears the allow block is being ignored

Comment: @MattWestlake try running `meteor remove insecure` in the meteor directory. by default meteor allows insecure writes to the db

Comment: @PaulNispel I just tried running it again to make sure and i got `insecure is not in this project.`

Comment: @MattWestlake haha have you tried turning it off and back on? If so I'm out of ideas. Does it work if you do the insert from the client side?

Comment: @PaulNispel I missed a section of the Mongo-Collection-allow code where it states `Keep in mind that server code and code inside methods are not affected by allow and deny — these rules only apply when insert, update, and remove are called from untrusted client code.`

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what `allow` does. It tells the *client* what is allowed and what is not. Moreover the signature of the `insert` command is not the same as that of the `allow`, as you are doing.

That said, the solution is to simply do the insert on the client:

```
Item.insert(item);
```

or, if you really want to do it via a method, then still just drop the first argument.

Comment: I dropped the first argument, but it still doesn't work.  If allow only works on the client, then I will need to implement my own check on the server.  Anything on the client can be forged/circumvented so I don't want the client to have any write access.

Comment: I would recommend reading more about meteor before concluding that it isn't secure. There is a reason why you have to define these `allow` rules *on the server*.